# Are there examples of visa-free travel agreements between countries that have no mutual extradition agreements whatsoever?

Tags: treaty, visa, freedom-of-movement, extradition

I imagine that lack of extradition treaties is somewhat of a hindrance for establishing visa-free travel between countries, on the argument that if (potential) criminals can enter freely (and then do some crime) one should be at least able to get them extradited thereafter. (Of course, visas are not a perfect protection against criminals entering.)

So, are there examples of visa-free travel agreements between countries that have no mutual extradition agreements whatsoever? In particular any such examples involving the US or EU countries?

Comment: Most visa-free travel is the result of unilateral action rather than bilateral agreement.

Comment: @phoog: I can imagine poor country giving visa-free travel to rich country to encourage tourism and what not, and so not asking for much if anything in return. Which is why I also asked if examples involving the not so poor US or EU countries exist (as the visa-free zone/giver).

Comment: So, apparently Ukraine had visa-free regime for Russian citizens. https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/ukraines-zelenskiy-orders-end-visa-free-travel-russians-2022-05-25/ I think Russia doesn't extradite to anywhere, including Ukraine. It is kinda odd that Ukraine apparently took 3 months after the Feb invasion to suspend that regime though, so I'm not sure how widespread/operational it still was...

Comment: Russia has [ratified](https://www.coe.int/en/web/conventions/full-list?module=signatures-by-treaty&treatynum=024) the European Convention on Extradition in 1999. It's one of the treaties under the auspices of the Council of Europe, but there are four non-member state signatoires: Israel, Russia, South Africa and Republic of Korea.

Comment: @ccprog: they registered a fairly giant exception upon signature, as far as  I can tell https://www.theguardian.com/world/2007/may/22/russia.lukeharding

Comment: If you look at [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extradition#Own_citizens), this exemption is not _that_ uncommon. The list was [even longer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Arrest_Warrant#Surrender_of_nationals) before the introductuin of the European Arrest warrant in 2004.

Comment: @ccprog: I think that Wikipedia claim is pretty misleading. For instance Germany "doesn't" extradite its citizen, oh well, except to the EU per footnote in that very page. And to the US as well if [sees fit](https://se-legal.de/schlun-elseven-lawyers/lawyer-for-extradition-proceedings/extradition-from-germany-to-the-usa/?lang=en) etc. Countries reserving the right to refuse extradition in specific cases or not giving *automatic* approval to all requests is different than not extraditing at all in any circumstances.

Comment: That is why I said "the list was longer": Art. 16 (2) GG was specifically [amended](https://lexetius.com/GG/16,2) in 2000 to allow for the European Arrest warrant. I didn't even notice Germany was still on the first list I linked. But the point is that prior to the addoption of that framework, the **majority** of EU countries did not extradite their own citizens.

Comment: N.B. On paper Russia has extradition agreeements with quite a few countries including e.g. 
[Ecuador](http://en.kremlin.ru/acts/news/64371) and [Thailand](https://tass.com/politics/1401301). So I'm guessing the prohibition in Russian law is hardly absolute either. I wouldn't be surprised if they have such treaties with CIS countries.

Comment: OTOH Putin said once “Never. Never. Russia does not extradite its citizens to anyone"  https://apnews.com/article/c5180bffb84d424ba11cf3384a665eb5 So I guess one should give a close reading to those treaties.

Comment: I did find the text of the India-Russia extradition treaty https://www.latestlaws.com/bare-acts/central-acts-rules/criminal-laws/the-extradition-act-1962/extradition-treaty-between-the-government-of-republic-of-india-and-the-russian-federation I looks pretty "standard" to me, which is to say it gives leeway to political decision making. including a pretty weird one "A person may not be extradited if
1.1 he is a citizen of the Requested Party, or [,,,]".

Comment: Reading between the lines, the whole/main point of the extradition treaties that Russia has signed with some countries (not the EU ones apparently) is to get their own Russian citizens "back" if they flee to such countries after being charged with some crime in Russia. (Amusing aside, Russia has a 1893 extradition treaty with the USA, but it's apparently not recognzied anymore https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/how-would-u-s-put-indicted-russians-trial-n891581 presumably so since Soviet times.)

Comment: I'm confused.  It's not clear who's being extradited where.  The point of _any_ extradition treaty is to get people back after they've been accused of a crime and then left the country -- regardless of their citizenship.  Did you think it was something different?  Did you imagine that Russians committing crimes in the US can't be deported to Russia because there's no (currently active) extradition treaty?  That's not the case at all.

Answer (score 2):

It is obviously too difficult to list all examples, but Canada allows visa-free access to passport holders of the following countries without an extradition agreement with Canada:

Andorra, Brunei, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Ireland, Liechtenstein, Morocco, Poland, Samoa, Seychelles, Slovakia, Slovenia, Taiwan, United Arab Emirates, Uruguay, Vatican City

Source: You can compare the [list](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/entry-requirements-country.html) of countries with visa-free access to Canada and the lists of countries that 1) [has an extradition treaty with Canada](https://cflaw.ca/practice-area/toronto-extradition-lawyer/extradition-which-countries-have-extradition-treaties-with-canada) or 2) [is a "designated extradition partner" of Canada](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/acts/E-23.01/page-6.html#h-213442)

Comment: This looks like a good answer, but, please, add references to the answer itself.  A user shouldn't have to google all your claims to verify them.

Comment: This is a bit misleading. The first list is describing "The following travellers need an Electronic Travel Authorization (eTA) to board their flight to Canada. However, these travellers do not need an eTA if entering by land or sea – for instance driving from the U.S. or coming by bus, train, or boat, including cruise ship." So a Bulgarian arriving **form Bulgaria** to Canada cannot enter without a visa. They can do so **only do so if they've already been admitted to the US**! So essentially, Canada is accepting visas granted by the US [too], which is somewhat different.

Comment: An yeah, as mentioned in a related Q, Bulgarians need a visa to enter the US: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/84168/is-there-an-official-reason-given-by-the-u-s-government-for-not-wanting-to-impl

Comment: An eTA is not a visa. Bulgarians from Bulgaria are officially "visa-exempt", but they still need an eTA. An eTA takes only a few minutes to complete.

Comment: @Fizz many of the other countries listed are US visa waiver program countries, so focusing on Bulgarians' inability to enter the US through the VWP is misleading.  But it also underscores Desk Reference's point: if you consider flying to the US under the VWP to be entering without a visa despite the fact that it requires ESTA authorization, then eTA is also not a visa.  If you insist on considering ESTA and eTA to be visas then Canada only grants visa free entry to citizens of one country, the US, and the US grants visa free entry to only two, Canada and Bermuda.

Answer (score 0):

The German constitution (in Article 16) forbids the extradition of German citizens, except to other EU member states or to international courts, so every non-EU country that allows visa-free travel for German citizens is an example.

Answer (score 0):

> I imagine that lack of extradition treaties is somewhat of a hindrance for establishing visa-free travel between countries, on the argument that if (potential) criminals can enter freely (and then do some crime) one should be at least able to get them extradited thereafter.

The purpose of visas and of visa exemptions has little to do with criminal justice or with the purpose of extradition treaties.

To the extent that a country uses visas to keep undesirable foreigners out, and to the extent that some foreigners are undesirable because they will commit crimes while they're in the country, consider that the existence of an extradition treaty with the foreigner's country of citizenship doesn't make it easier to get the foreigner out of the country after conviction, because *that's not extradition; it's deportation.*  No treaty is needed.

The purpose of an extradition treaty is to get someone who is accused of committing a crime in your country *into* your country so you can prosecute them.  (You can deport them afterward, if they're not a citizen of your country.)  The only advantage of an extradition treaty is that you are more likely to be able to bring criminals to justice who have visited your country and committed a crime there and then left the country before they could be arrested.